# Node JS send a file from client to server

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am trying to send a file(XML) and to receive it using Node JS server/client tools.

Here I tried to send a simple message.

**server.js**

```
var PORT = 33333;
var HOST = '127.0.0.1';

var dgram = require('dgram');
var server = dgram.createSocket('udp4');

server.on('listening', function () {
    var address = server.address();
    console.log('UDP Server listening on ' + address.address + ":" + address.port);
});

server.on('message', function (message, remote) {
    console.log(remote.address + ':' + remote.port +' - ' + message);

});

server.bind(PORT, HOST);
```

**client.js**

```
var PORT = 33333;
var HOST = '127.0.0.1';

var dgram = require('dgram');
var message = new Buffer('It works, you have received me !');

var client = dgram.createSocket('udp4');

client.send(message, 0, message.length, PORT, HOST, function(err, bytes) {
    if (err) throw err;
    console.log('UDP message sent to ' + HOST +':'+ PORT);
    client.close();
});
```

Here everything works, using client.js I am able to send a message to server.js who can receive it.

My problem is that I need to send not a message but a XML file and to be able to receive it as well. I found that i need to use sendFile() but I have no idea how to use it in my code.
I am new to nodeJS can someone help me?

Comment: sendFile() is what your looking for.

Comment: i found this function before but i cant implement it, have no idea, can you provide an example? Thank you.

Comment: If you're sending a file, you probably will want to use tcp and not udp.

Comment: I dont know much about XML or dgran or what your doing exactly, but I will post an example for just a simple node/express server.

Comment: But in case i need to use only UDP is it possible to send and receive a file ?  @mscdex

Comment: UDP has quite strict limit on length of message, imho less than 512 bytes, so sending XML file can be tricky. you need to cut it into pieces, and than gather it back on client. Also you will need to verify, that parts of file are delivered, because UDP is unrelaible protocol. I think using TCP is preffered here.